# How to get Azure VM's disk utilization details using Java SDK or REST API?

Tags: rest, azure-java-sdk

I am able to get Azure VM's actual disk size by using Java SDK.
But i want to know how much disk is utilized. Is there any way to get utilized size of disk using Java SDK or REST API?